# AngularJS UI Bootstrap popover using ng-repeat data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an ng-repeat and I need to use the current object in the iteration to create the body of uib-popover content.

I have tried uib-popover-html but I get an angular unsafe context error.  I tried a function that returns an HTML string using $sce but that failed as well.

Is there a way to build the content of a popover message inside an ng-repeat using the current object in the sequence?

**Update**

@Claies: This is a sample of the code I was trying to use

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', myModule])
 
 function myModule($scope, $sce) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.getPopoverData = function(s) {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml('<ul><li>' + s.Value1 + '</li><li>' + s.Value2 + '</li></ul>');
  }
 }
})();
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="s in vm.sequences>
 <button uib-popover-html="vm.getPopoverData(s)" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="value btn">s.text</button>
</div>
<!-- This returns Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations -->

    <div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="s in vm.sequences>
 <button uib-popover-html="'<ul><li>{{s.value1}}</li><li>{{s.value2}}</li></ul>'" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="value btn">s.text</button>
</div>
<!-- This returns Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context. -->
```

Thank you

Comment: the current object can be passed as a parameter to a function, so yes, you can definitely use it, assuming you are setting up the popover correctly;  can you post the code illustrating what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have posted a snippet of what I tried.

Comment: the format of that HTML snippet is all wrong.  You can't use variables directly in the HTML like that, without using an expression `{{ }}`; however, you also can't use expressions for variables that are being saved as HTML in another variable;  Perhaps you could try concatenating the HTML string (i.e. `'<ul><li>' + s.Value1 + '</li>' ...`)

Comment: I apologize, that is what I meant.  I have updated the code.  The problem with this code is that the function gets called on the mouseentere event not when the loop executes and I get the following error: `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations`  Thank you.

Comment: I have also tried `uib-popover-html="'<ul><li>Heat Number: {{sequence.HeatNumber}} </li></ul>'"...` but I get this error: `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context`

Comment: the "unsafe value in a safe context" error was exactly what I meant when I said you can't use expressions in another variable.  However, if you were able to compile the expressions, they would yield the same output as the concatenated one, and presumably cause the second error.  Normally, the second error occurs when you are changing your data; nothing in this code suggests that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue using the function code as follows

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', myModule])
 
 function myModule($scope, $sce) {
  var vm = this;
                vm.trusted = {};
  vm.getPopoverData = function(s) {
                        var html = '<ul><li>' + s.Value1 + '</li><li>' + s.Value2 + '</li></ul>';
   return trusted[html] || (trusted[html] = $sce.trustAsHtml(html));
  }
 }
})();
```

This stopped the looping error and made the popover appear correctly.

Thank you Claies for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', myModule])

function myModule($scope, $sce) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.trusted = [];
    vm.getPopoverData = function(s) {
         var html = '<ul><li>' + s.Value1 + '</li><li>' + s.Value2 + '</li></ul>';
         trusted[html] || (trusted[html] = $sce.trustAsHtml(html));
         return trusted[html];
    }
}
})();
```